# go from activty A to B and come back to A android

Tags: android

I have read a lot but still havn't got my full answer.
When starting app A,within onCreate method I get data from Api and set on ListView.
Here also I have button and when I click to it I am going to Activity B and send some data.
Within my B activity I send data to my api and if response status is ok I want to go back to activity A and reload data:call oncreate method in wich located my call function to api.
In my manifest I have set
 `<activity android:name=".A"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance" ></activity>`

but when I call startActivity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this,A.class);
              Bundle b = new Bundle();
              String from = "upload";
              b.putString("action", from);
              startActivity(i);
```

I dont start activty A from point onCreate.
I have already tried call finish() function after going to activity B but this doesn't get my any result.
I want to append that in A activity I get file from gallery and pass uri to activity B.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to start a child activity with the intention of receiving a result, don't use `startActivity()`. Use `startActivityForResult()` instead. You will also need to implement (override) a method in your main activity to be called when the result is ready.

Comment: I am new in android,can you write wich method I must implement

Comment: onActivityResult() needs to be implemented. When B finish()s, A's onActivityResult() will be called. It will include B's result code (which B can set with setResult() before it calls finish(), and with a request code defined by A (to allow A to distinguish between multiple child activities). It will also have any data B returned back to A. http://rahulonblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-startactivityforresult-example.html seems to have an example though I've not used that page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back to A and you need `onCreate` call `finish()` in A after `startActivity(B)`. This way, `onCreate` will get called again when you go back to A (since it was destroyed).

Note that this is not a good way to handle things. A better method would be to move the "getting data from Api" part to `onResume` in activity A.

LATER EDIT: Indeed, `startActivityForResult()` is the way to go in this situation, no need to over-complicate things. Note to self: go for the easier route from now on.

Comment: I tried this,but when in activity B I write startActivity(A) I get an exception.

Comment: Sorry,i have one stupid mistake,within A I expect extra and from B I didn't pass them.Thanks for help!

Comment: Android's startActivityForResult() is exactly intended to provide B's result back to A. There's no redeeming value to mucking with onCreate() and onResume() to solve this.

Comment: @mah: True. I was too focused on "making it work this way" too see the easier solution.